# One form three tables in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to create a single form to save data to 3 tables. 3 tables are connected with one to many relation.

I am able to save data to brandname but not to producttype and sub category.

below is the code:

```
<%= form_for(@brandname, :html => {class: "form-horizontal", role: "form"}) do |f| %>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
          <%= f.label :brandname %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <%= f.text_field :brandname, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Enter Brand Name" %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.fields_for :producttype do |builder| %>
          <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
            <%= builder.label :content, "Type Of Product" %><br />
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            <%= builder.text_field :content, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Enter Product Type" %>
          </div>
        <% end %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.fields_for :subcategories do |builder| %>
          <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
            <%= builder.label :content, "Sub Category" %><br />
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            <%= builder.text_field :content, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Enter Sub Category" %>
          </div>
        <% end %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
          <%= f.submit(@brandname.new_record? ? "Add" : "Save", class: 'btn btn-primary btn-lg') %>
          <%= link_to "Cancel", new_brandname_path, class: "btn btn-default btn-lg active" %>
        </div>
      </div>      
    <% end %>
```

Controller:

```
  def new
    @brandname   = Brandname.new
    @brandname.producttypes.build
    producttype.subcategories.build
  end

  def create
    @brandname = Brandname.new(prodinfo_params)
    if @brandname.save
      flash[:success] = "ProductInfo Created Successfully"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private
  def prodinfo_params
    params.require(:brandname).permit(:brandname, :producttype, :subcategory )
    # producttype_attributes: [:producttype]
  end

Model:

Brandname:

class Brandname < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :producttypes, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :producttypes
end

Producttype:

class Producttype < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :brandname
  has_many :subcategories, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :subcategories
end


Sub Category:

class Subcategory < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :producttype
end
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Strong parameters is wrong, take a look here at the second example with nested attributes http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%= form_for(@brandname, :html => {class: "form-horizontal", role: "form", :multipart => true}) do |f| %>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
          <%= f.label :brandname %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <%= f.text_field :brandname, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Enter Brand Name" %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.fields_for :producttypes do |builder| %>
          <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
            <%= builder.label :producttype, "Type Of Product" %><br />
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            <%= builder.text_field :producttype, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Enter Product Type" %>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <%= builder.fields_for :subcategories do |builder_sub| %>
            <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
              <%= builder_sub.label :subcategory, "Sub Category" %><br />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <%= builder_sub.text_field :subcategory, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Enter Sub Category" %>
            </div>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
```

Params:

```
params.require(:brandname).permit(:brandname, producttypes_attributes: [:id, :brandname_id, :producttype, subcategories_attributes: [:id, :producttype_id, :subcategory]])
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you described what is happening other than saying the producttype and subcategory aren't saving. Look in the logs when you save and I suspect you'll see a message regarding the association attributes not being permitted.

The productinfo_params in the controller needs to permit the attributes of the associations e.g.

```
def prodinfo_params
  params.require(:brandname).permit(:brandname, producttypes_attributes: [:content, subcategory_attributes: [:content]]) )
end
```

Comment: (byebug) prodinfo_params
Unpermitted parameters: producttype, subcategories
<ActionController::Parameters {"brandname"=>"Dettol"} permitted: true>

Comment: That error message is giving you a clue - add the unpermitted parameters to the permitted parameters. Also look at the params hash to see how the form parameters should be formatted.

Answer (score 0):

also need to update his second builder object in template

as subcategory is nested form productType not from brandname

```
<div class="form-group">
    <%= f.fields_for :producttype do |builder| %>
      <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
        <%= builder.label :content, "Type Of Product" %><br />
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <%= builder.text_field :content, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Enter Product Type" %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= builder.fields_for :subcategories do |cat_builder| %>
          <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
            <%= cat_builder.label :content, "Sub Category" %><br />
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            <%= cat_builder.text_field :content, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Enter Sub Category" %>
          </div>
        <% end %>
       </div>
    <% end %>
 </div>
```

Comment: undefined local variable or method `builder' for #<#<Class:0x007fbcb86d8f90>:0x007fbcadde2120>

Comment: you should move it up to be inside the first nested attributes , 
i updated my answer to include the full nested objects